# Weird behavior CSS overflow-y

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a scrolling menu that has a list of cards, Each card has a button that shows more information.
the problem is that the overflow-y property hides the (toggled info) that should appear at the left side of the menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VAoJ.png)

as you can see in the picture, I wanna get the (overflow-x visible) for the card-list but making it overflow-y: auto/scroll simply hide it

code Sandbox if you wanna take a look at the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Machfar-Souhayel/TestingOverflowBehavior

Comment: minimal code to reproduce the error should be included in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could have the expanded version outside of the original list and just alter it to fit the item and then make it visible.
It also is not nessesary to create a class that make it visible/invisible and add and remove that with toggledElement.classList.add("show");
Instead just use element.style.display = 'block'; // 'none';
That way you do not need to use the target.children property but can call the function with an argument.

```
<button onclick="toggleClass('Title','Content');">Expand</button>

<script>
function toggleClass(header, content){
   document.getElementsByClassName('expanded')[0].innerHtml = `<h1>${header}</h1><br><p>${content}</p>`;
   document.getElementsByClassName('expanded')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
<style>
   .expanded{
      position: abolute;
      top: 50vh;
      left: 50vw;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50);//just for some styling
      display: none;
   }
</style>
<div class="expanded"></div>
```

I hope I could help you.